# What's the best way to get the common and different rows between two tables in SQL Server?

Tags: html, asp.net, sql-server

I'm working on a project where I compare two devices. I want to get both the differences and what's common for let's say available 3g technologies of said devices while keeping the order, what's common will be put in a span while the rest will be plain text.
I've tried the following:

```
SELECT n.name AS modif, n.name FROM device_networks
JOIN networks n ON n.id = network_id
JOIN network_technologies nt ON nt.id = n.tech_id
WHERE G=3 AND device_id = 77 
AND n.name NOT IN(
SELECT n.name FROM device_networks
JOIN networks n ON n.id = network_id
JOIN network_technologies nt ON nt.id = n.tech_id
WHERE G=3 AND device_id = 10
INTERSECT
SELECT n.name FROM device_networks
JOIN networks n ON n.id = network_id
JOIN network_technologies nt ON nt.id = n.tech_id
WHERE G=3 AND device_id = 77
)
UNION
SELECT CONCAT('<span class=''dif''>', n.name,'</span>') AS modif, n.name FROM device_networks
JOIN networks n ON n.id = network_id
JOIN network_technologies nt ON nt.id = n.tech_id
WHERE G=3 AND device_id = 77 
AND n.name IN(
SELECT n.name FROM device_networks
JOIN networks n ON n.id = network_id
JOIN network_technologies nt ON nt.id = n.tech_id
WHERE G=3 AND device_id = 10
INTERSECT
SELECT n.name FROM device_networks
JOIN networks n ON n.id = network_id
JOIN network_technologies nt ON nt.id = n.tech_id
WHERE G=3 AND device_id = 77
)
ORDER BY name DESC
```

But it seems too big which makes me think there's a different way to go at it. I'll be using a function for the subquery but if there's a better way to go at it, please let me know! Thanks.

EDIT:

Here's the output

[image: Here's the output]

Here's part of the schema

[image: Here's part of the schema]

Comment: Without knowing the schema of your tables and what output you're expecting, it's impossible for us to assist you. Consider providing examples of your data and the output.

Comment: @IanKemp I've added the output and schema but I'm not sure how it would help, I wanted to get both the different and common rows at the same time between two tables.

Comment: how about some sample data and the corresponding expected result

Comment: @Squirrel what I'm getting is the expected result, I want to know if there's a better way to get said result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not 100% certain on the usage of the above query but it can be shortened up with a CTE like

```
;WITH Intersected_CTE AS(

    SELECT 
        n.name 
    FROM 
        device_networks
            JOIN networks n ON n.id = network_id
            JOIN network_technologies nt ON nt.id = n.tech_id
    WHERE 
        G=3 
        AND device_id = 10

    INTERSECT

    SELECT 
        n.name 
    FROM 
        device_networks
            JOIN networks n ON n.id = network_id
            JOIN network_technologies nt ON nt.id = n.tech_id
    WHERE 
        G=3 
        AND device_id = 10
)
SELECT n.name AS modif, n.name FROM device_networks
JOIN networks n ON n.id = network_id
JOIN network_technologies nt ON nt.id = n.tech_id
WHERE G=3 AND device_id = 77 
AND n.name NOT IN(
    SELECT 
        n.name 
    FROM
        Intersected_CTE
)

UNION

SELECT CONCAT('<span class=''dif''>', n.name,'</span>') AS modif, n.name FROM device_networks
JOIN networks n ON n.id = network_id
JOIN network_technologies nt ON nt.id = n.tech_id
WHERE G=3 AND device_id = 77 
AND n.name IN(
    SELECT 
        n.name 
    FROM
        Intersected_CTE
)
ORDER BY name DESC
```

Comment: yep, I put the intersection in a function because I lost hope about there being another way lol.
Thanks for your help!